# Getting 403 in Facebook sharing debugger

Tags: angular, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

I'm looking for a good way to implement og tags on my angular application,
on my hosted site, when I load certain page, the network tab says 403 but the page loads,
I found this is the reason Facebook sharing debugger is not recognizing the OG tags,
is there any way to overcome this issue?
and also I was referring youtube,
when I inspect their page og tags are not available, but when I share all the details shows up.
how can I achieve that

I'm using a service which sets meta tags on page init, I cant test it because of 403